# Objects created with "arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion" are shown in Google Earth Places with [no name]

Tags: arcpy, kml, google-earth, arcgis-pro

When I create a kml file from an ArcGIS Pro layer using "arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion" all objects are shown in Google Earth Places (left pane) with [no name]. The piece of code doing this is as simple as this:

```
fc_node_live_available = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Optimity_Equipment.gdb', 'Node_Live_Available')
kml_node_live_available = os.path.join(out_path, 'Node_Live_Available.kmz')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_node_live_available, 'Node Live Available')
arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion('Node Live Available', kml_node_live_available, is_composite = 'NO_COMPOSITE', ignore_zvalue = 'ABSOLUTE')
```

However, when I do the same thing using the tool box ('Layer to kml' tool). Objects will show their name in Google Earth when importing the kml file.

Is there anything I am missing on my arcpy code?

Comment: If you right click the result from the results tab after running manually from the toolbox and select copy as python snippet, can you see any difference between your code and the copied snippet?

Comment: No difference. Actually I found a weird way to make it work.

If I first create the map layers I need (using a script) and later on I convert to KFL (with a DIFFERENT script), it works fine (names appear on Google Earth).
If I do both things on the same script, it doesn't work ([no name] appears on Google Earth).

I don't have the faintest idea of why this is behaving that way.

Comment: What about `lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(etc...).GetOutput(0)` then `arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(lyr, etc...) `?

Comment: Sorry, `getOutput` http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm

Comment: Just realised before you added the comment and deleted my comment :-)

Comment: So, just tried and no, it doesn't do the job unfortunately. I'll have to keep doing this using 2 separate scripts (how weird is that).

Comment: One more thing to try is saving the layer object to file`lyr.saveACopy (file_name)` and pass the file name to the layer to kml tool.

Comment: I'm actually using 'SaveToLayerFile_management' to create layer files. Is that any different to 'saveACopy'?

Comment: Converting the layer files directly to a kml file does not work. So, I have to add those layers to my map (feature layers) and then I convert those feature layers to kml. That works. (the reason I create those layer files is because it's the only way I have found to add a layer to the map  =>  .addLayer)